# elfinder 2.1 cwd order

Tags: jquery, sorting, elfinder

Do you know anybody, how can i set cwd/sidebar order?

```
sortType: 'date',
sortOrder: 'desc',
```

I use these parameters, and it is work perfectly on the right side, but the left side order doesnt change.

The right side now sort by ABC, so i thinks it use "sort by name" option maybe.

I tried to fine the setting in elfinder.full.js file but i can not.

Please help!

Best Regards,

Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set `sortAlsoTreeview: true`.

However, these settings are memorized in the browser.